# static inline member of a class initializing OK compiling with g++ but errs with clang

Tags: c++, clang

Have a very simple example c++ project.
foo.h:

```
class foo{  
    inline static const int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };  
};
```

foo.cc:

```
#include "foo.h"

foo a_foo;
```

main.cc:

```
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
    foo b_foo;
}
```

When compile with g++ by the following command:

```
g++ -c *.cc
g++ *.o -o a.out
```

It just reports the warning:

```
In file included from foo.cc:2:0:
foo.h:2:25: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
 inline static const int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
                         ^~~~~
In file included from main.cc:3:0:
foo.h:2:25: warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
 inline static const int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
                         ^~~~~
```

But when compile with clang by the following command:

```
clang -c *.cc
clang *.o -o a.out
```

or even using the command:

```
clang -std=c++1z -c *.cc
clang -std=c++1z *.o -o a.out
```

It reports the error:

```
In file included from foo.cc:2:
./foo.h:2:1: error: 'inline' can only appear on functions
inline static const int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
^
./foo.h:2:25: error: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const int [3]' requires 'constexpr' specifier
inline static const int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
                        ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~
constexpr
2 errors generated.
In file included from main.cc:3:
./foo.h:2:1: error: 'inline' can only appear on functions
inline static const int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
^
./foo.h:2:25: error: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const int [3]' requires 'constexpr' specifier
inline static const int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
                        ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~
constexpr
2 errors generated.
```

Have tried several modification but all failed. How to rectify the code so it also compiles OK with clang?

Comment: `inline static` member variables are a C++17 feature.  Looks like (your) g++ is defaulting to an earlier standard.  Try specifying `-std=c++17` (or later) on the command line.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes. You are right. Adding -std=c++17 to compile with g++ and there is no warning output at all. But how to deal with clang? I can only use clang!

Comment: (Recent versions of) clang support the very same command line argument `-std=c++17`. The other question is how old are the compilers (g++ and clang) you have installed...

Answer (score 0):

OK. I upgraded clang to the version 15.0 seems to solve the problem. Thanks for all your help!